# Liquid: How to get product title in `abandoned_cart` email?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to inject some custom liquid in my abandoned cart email on Shopify. Shopify has docs [here](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/promoting-marketing/create-marketing/shopify-email/create-email/custom-liquid) saying the `product_title` can be found under `line_items` under `abandoned_cart`.

I naturally assume you can get the `product_title` with something akin to...

```
<p>You left {{ abandoned_checkout.line_items[0].product_title }} in your cart.</p>
```

But this doesn't work. What's the proper way to get the product name of the first item?

Comment: As far as I can see the doc points that the object is available for abandoned chackout automation:
"The abandoned_checkout variable populates only if an email is part of an abandoned checkout marketing automation. Otherwise, the variable will be null."
So if you're working on notification templates this won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with email template for "Abandoned checkout" in notification settings, this should work:

```
{{ subtotal_line_items[0].product.title }}
```

Loop code:

```
{% for line in subtotal_line_items %}
   {{ line.product.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

And here is some useful documentation here:
https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/notifications/email-variables#line-item

Answer (score 1):

All products for the abandoned cart will keep here: `subtotal_line_items` and you should operate with the Product object. So in the your case it should be:

```
<p>You left {{ subtotal_line_items[0].product.title }} in your cart.</p>
```